# IPAD Block tap/touch on all other subviews of a View when one of them is being touched

Tags: ipad

So I have an ipad app under construction. I have a two big views, and out of them one has a dozen or so smaller views. These smaller views have buttons inside them. Whenever i touch the button in any of these views, the replica of the view gets added to the other bigger view. All this functionality works fine. Now what I would like to achieve is, I should be able to do that tap on only a single smaller view at any given point of time. That is I should not be able to tap on multiple views at the same time. Can anyone guide me through?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself and with the help of @SmallVille in chat forums.